# No signature of method: build_79k99zzpu1czozbhubqf5bc4h.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_79k99zzpu1czozbhubqf5bc4h$_run_closure1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, data-binding, build.gradle

i'm trying to add databiding in my code but when i try to sync shows me an error:

No signature of method: build_79k99zzpu1czozbhubqf5bc4h.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_79k99zzpu1czozbhubqf5bc4h$_run_closure1) values: [build_79k99zzpu1czozbhubqf5bc4h$_run_closure1@493dc88e]

this is the code:

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCaaq.png) [code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt053.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by writing:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

instead of:

```
dataBiding{
    enabled = true
}
```